# Unable to set runtime Local Server Port in Spring Boot Test 1.5

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-boot, webserver

I am using Spring Boot 1.5 for my application. In integration testing I want to fetch the runtime port number of the web server(note: TestRestTemplate is not useful in my case.). There are a few approaches I have tried but none of them seem to work. Below are my approaches.

**First Approach**

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfig.class, webEnvironment =WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class RestServiceTest {

@LocalServerPort      
protected int port;
```

In my `src/main/resources/config/application.properties` file I have defined server port as

> server.port = 8081

But With this code I am getting error

> Could not resolve placeholder 'local.server.port' in value "${local.server.port}"

**Second Approach**

I have changed

> webEnvironment =WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT

to

> webEnvironment =WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT

and in my `src/main/resources/config/application.properties` file I have defined

> server.port = 0

This throws the same as error as the first approach.

**Third Approach**

In third approach I have tried to use

```
protected int port;

@Autowired
Environment environment

this.port = this.environment.getProperty("local.server.port");
```

this returns `null` value

**Fourth Approach**

Lastly I have tried to use `ApplicationEvents` to find out the port number by creating an event listener to listen to `EmbeddedServletContainerIntialize`

```
@EventListener(EmbeddedServletContainerInitializedEvent.class)
public void onApplicationEvent(EmbeddedServletContainerInitializedEvent event) {
this.port = event.getEmbeddedServletContainer().getPort();
}

public int getPort() {
return this.port;
}
```

Added the same to `TestConfig`

Now, In my test class I have tried use this listener to get the port

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfig.class, webEnvironment =WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class RestServiceTest {

protected int port;

@Autowired
EmbeddedServletContainerIntializedEventListener embeddedServletcontainerPort;

this.port = this.embeddedServletcontainerPort.getPort();
```

this returns `0`. Also, I have found out listener event is never triggered.

It is very straight forward as in the docs and other posts but somehow It is not working for me. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is `TestCOnfig` your actual application class? As that is what should be loaded (as that contains the `@SpringBootAPplication` annotation and triggers all things).

Comment: @M.Deinum `TestConfig` is a `@Configuration` file specific to test environment where other beans are defined.

Comment: Then it won't work.. It requires a full application configuration else the application won't start nor auto-configure and hence no ports will be set.

Comment: @M.Deinum The same configuration was working in 1.3.8. Also I have tried getting the port in a dummy application without declaring the main class and it works and returns the port.

Comment: Things change between major versions. It might even depend on the package (and if things are detected). I would suggest trying to define both the application class and test config in the annotation.

Comment: 1st approach....2nd approach...3rd approach... 4th approach. And therein is the problem. _Spring is a mess_. I feel your pain and am currently going through the exact same fight, hence finding your question.

Answer (score 17):

Maybe you forgot to configure the random port for your test web environment.

This should do the trick:
`@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)`

Here a test just executed successfully with Spring Boot 1.5.2:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.greaterThan;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class RandomPortTests {

    @Value("${local.server.port}")
    protected int localPort;

    @Test
    public void getPort() {
        assertThat("Should get a random port greater than zero!", localPort, greaterThan(0));
    }

}
```

Comment: Please could you expand your answer to show the dependencies which you have imported (presumably using Maven?). I have the same code as you but it doesn't work for me. There must be some config which I am missing.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue with an application using spring boot 1.4 and found that the event of `EmbeddedServletContainerInitializedEvent` is a bit delayed - which means it gets triggered after my bean is initialized -, so in order to resolve this i needed to use lazy annotation on the bean that needs to use the port as for example a RestClient bean and it worked.
Example:

```
@Bean
@Lazy(true)
public RESTClient restClient() {
   return new RESTClient(URL + port)
}
```

Comment: This was the solution for me.

Comment: This solved the same error with a usage of `@LocalServerPort` in a `@Component` injected into a `@RestController`.  
Minor note: `@Lazy(true)` can simply be `@Lazy`.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to put `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` above your class decoration.

So, try this.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfig.class, webEnvironment =WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class RestServiceTest {
     @LocalServerPort
     int randomServerPort;
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Adding this dependency solved the problem:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-spring -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This seems to be completely not related to the root issue. This is not a part of Spring Framework or Spring Boot.